# How do you specify a integer literal as a WORD?

Tags: visual-c++, integer, code-analysis, cpu-word

I have this code:

```
bool bIsSampleConversationVideo = 
        m_aryWStudentAssignTypeIndex[wItem - 1] == 
        CChristianLifeMinistryDefines::kSampleConversationVideo;
```

When I compile with code analysis in 64 bit I get the following warning for `[wItem - ]`:

> LNT1000 A sub-expression may overflow before being assigned to a wider type.

When I hover the mouse over the two items I see:

- `wItem` is of type `WORD`
- `1` is of type `int`

I know that you can add [suffixes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) to literal numbers, like `L` etc. but don't find out how to specify a integer literal as a `WORD`.

---

It is possible that I have miss-interpreted the warning. Either way, is there a simple resolution to prevent the code analysis warning?

Comment: `WORD(1)`. That said, I must admit I don't understand what the warning is trying to say. `wItem` would be promoted to `int` before the subtraction; this expression is not at risk of overflowing an `unsigned short` aka `WORD`. Maybe it thinks `wItem` could be zero and so `wItem-1` could be negative, and overflow `size_t` (the type of the array index)?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Good point. But the `for` loop this code is inside starts at `1`: `for (WORD wItem = 1; wItem <= 4; wItem++)` So we won't ever get a `0 - xx` scenario.

Comment: Well, linter might not be smart enough to realize that.